# Pandas eval with backslash in column names

Tags: python, pandas, eval, backslash

I have a dataframe like this

```
df=pd.DataFrame([1,2,3],columns=['a\\b'])

 a\b
0    1
1    2
2    3
```

and I want to evaluate as expression like 'a\b<2' on this dataframe.

```
df.eval('a\\b<2')
```

When I do that I receive the following error message:

```
a \b <2
           ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Does anyone know how can I handle this sittuation? I can't change the column name because this is how the data comes from the datasource (and OPC server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `eval` when the column name is not a valid python variable name (starts with letter/underscore, letters/numbers/underscore only)

You should do instead:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3],columns=['a\\b'])
df['a\\b'].lt(2)
```

output:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: a\b, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Or use raw string `df[r'a\b'].lt(2)`

Comment: it doesn't work either. I think I will need to handle the sittuation in another way. Thanks to clarify.

Comment: @Dariva how does it "*not work*"? Please give details. The method I gave you won't trigger a `SyntexError`, do you have something else?

Comment: Sorry. It read you comment wrongly. What I meant was that df.eval(r'a\b<2') don't work either.